# Replace values in data frame column with results of aggregate/cut

Tags: r

**Edit: Modified simulated data so that price means/medians and neighborhoods don't overlap perfectly.**

I have a column in a dataframe, we'll call it Price. I'm just simulating data here:

```
mydata = data.frame(index = rep(1:1000))
mydata$price[1:300]    = rnorm(250, mean = 10000, sd = 1000)
mydata$price[301:550]  = rnorm(250, mean = 25000, sd = 1000)
mydata$price[551:775]  = rnorm(250, mean = 75000, sd = 1000)
mydata$price[776:1000] = rnorm(250, mean = 100000, sd = 1000)
```

And a set of neighborhoods, we'll call it Hoods:

```
mydata$hoods = factor(c(rep('hood1',250),rep('hood2',250),rep('hood3',250),rep('hood4',250)))
```

Then I aggregate the neighborhoods by the median price to create a median bin. I'd like to bin neighborhoods by their median price.

```
agg <- aggregate(mydata$price, by = list(hoods), FUN = median))
```

Then I create a cut version of the neighborhood medians (in my actual data there are 24 neighborhoods). So something like:

```
cut_aggregates <- cut(agg$x, breaks = c(0, 25000, 70000, 110000), labels = c('low','medium','high'))
```

I then want to replace the value of every 'hood1' in the original data with the aggregated price label, and so on for all the Neighborhoods. SO the first 250 records would be 'low', for example. I know I could make some nested if statement, or brute-force hard-coding. Does anyone know a way I can more efficiently assign all the values in one go, as I may use this for datasets larger than 1000 records. Thank you very much for any help you may provide.

in the final output, the categorized neighborhood ('low', 'medium', 'high') won't necessarily be the same as just doing a `cut` on price from the original data, because some neighborhood will have a combination of 'low', 'medium', and 'high' using this strategy. I want to first categorize each neighborhood based on its aggregate, and THEN recode the neighborhood.

Comment: Why don't you just do `cut(mydata$price, breaks ...)`?

Comment: I thought about it, but I didn't think that would break them based on the median price.

Comment: You just have to set the breaks correctly.

Comment: But my issue is I want all records in a particular neighborhood to be the same factor level on the median price. I think the solution to cut based on price, won't do this.

Comment: I've confirmed that using this method won't work because some houses in a neighborhood get categorized as high and some as medium, which is why I did the aggregate intermediary step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple way to do this, and probably the fastest, is to use `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)

# convert mydata into a data.table
  setDT(mydata)

# calculate median price by hood 
  mydata[, med := median(price), by=hoods]
```

now you can either:

```
# replace the original data of `hoods` with the new price labels
  mydata[, hoods := cut(med, breaks = c(0, 25000, 70000, 110000), labels = c('low','medium','high'))]

# or create new price labels in a new column
  mydata[, new_col := cut(med, breaks = c(0, 25000, 70000, 110000), labels = c('low','medium','high'))]
```

Finally, if you want just a summary table for each hood:

```
  mydata[, (med = median(price)), by=.(hoods, new_col)]

 >    hoods my_cut        V1
 > 1: hood1    low  9916.564
 > 2: hood2    low 24696.864
 > 3: hood3   high 74749.481
 > 4: hood4   high 99852.744
```

Comment: I tried this method, and the last line seems to do what I need, but maybe I'm missing something

Comment: Creating a new column of the replacement values ('low', 'med', 'high') is also acceptable, in addition to replacing hoods with the new values.

Comment: I always prefer to create new columns, keeping the original data intact for future reference

Comment: As far as I can  tell this gives me what I want, so thank you. Thanks too to @Sathis. His response works too.

Comment: @PatrickWilliams I added another approach that does similar operation as that of this data table solution

Comment: @Sathish Thank you! I appreciate your thoughtfulness. I really learned a lot from both answers.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: **Approach 1**

```
mydata <- within(mydata, med <- ave(price, hoods, FUN = median) )
mydata$new_label <- cut(mydata$med, breaks = c(0, 25000, 70000, 110000), labels = c('low','medium','high'))

#   index     price hoods      med new_label
# 1     1 10084.756 hood1 10014.38       low
# 2     2 10226.460 hood1 10014.38       low
# 3     3 10432.556 hood1 10014.38       low
# 4     4 10558.065 hood1 10014.38       low
# 5     5 10059.755 hood1 10014.38       low
# 6     6  9885.359 hood1 10014.38       low
```

**Approach2:**

Since `agg$labs` is not unique for each level of `hoods` in `mydata`, it will be better to reassign labels individually using a loop by mapping the levels of `hoods` with the values of `agg$labs`.

If you had unique labels in `agg$labs` for each levels of `hoods` in `mydata`, then it will be very simple to just reassign labels by doing `mydata$hoods <- factor( mydata$hoods, levels = agg$Group.1, labels = agg$labs )`. However you have duplicated levels in `agg$labs`, so you will follow the steps below.

```
mydata$hoods <- as.character( mydata$hoods )  # convert factor to character
agg$labs <- as.character(agg$labs)    # convert factor to character

for( i in seq_len( nrow( agg ) ) ) {  # change labels for hoods in mydata
  mydata[ mydata$hoods %in% agg$Group.1[ i ], "hoods" ] <- agg$labs[i]
} 
mydata$hoods <- factor( mydata$hoods )  # convert hoods back to factor

unique(mydata$hoods)   # output
# [1] low    medium high  
# Levels: high low medium
```

**Data:**

```
set.seed( 200 )
mydata = data.frame(index = rep(1:1000))
mydata$price[1:250]    = rnorm(250, mean = 10000, sd = 1000)
mydata$price[251:500]  = rnorm(250, mean = 25000, sd = 1000)
mydata$price[501:750]  = rnorm(250, mean = 75000, sd = 1000)
mydata$price[751:1000] = rnorm(250, mean = 100000, sd = 1000)
mydata$hoods = factor(c(rep('hood1',250),rep('hood2',250),rep('hood3',250),rep('hood4',250)))
agg <- with(mydata, aggregate( price, by = list(hoods), FUN = median) )
agg$labs <- cut(agg$x, breaks = c(0, 25000, 70000, 110000), labels = c('low','medium','high'))

agg
#   Group.1         x   labs
# 1   hood1  10014.38    low
# 2   hood2  25021.96 medium
# 3   hood3  74963.40   high
# 4   hood4 100019.88   high
```

The data in `agg` will vary if you choose a different seed in `set.seed()` function.

Comment: I wasn't familiar with the `ave` function. Thanks!